# How to handle single quote in a translatable string in Wordpress

Tags: translation

I have two translatable strings as follows in my 404.php file

```
esc_html_e( 'I couldn't find the page you were looking for.', 'themename' );
esc_html_e( 'Try a search or one of the links below.', 'themename' );
```

At its present form, the first string does not get translated. Escaping the single quote with a backslash does not help either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Easiest way out is simply write 'could not', though there's probably a smarter way.

Comment: Right, but that makes it formal. Besides, I prefer to know a solution to this problem in terms of programming and learn something. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it inside double quotes:

```
esc_html_e("I couldn't find the page you are looking for.", "themename");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape the single quote:

```
esc_html_e( 'I couldn\'t find the page you were looking for.', 'themename' );
```

But the [PHP Coding Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#single-and-double-quotes) of WordPress recommend to *not escape* any characters:

> **Single and Double Quotes**
>
> Use single and double quotes when appropriate. If you’re not
>   evaluating anything in the string, use single quotes. You should
>   almost never have to escape quotes in a string, because you can just
>   alternate your quoting style.

So you are probably better of, using double quotes as stated by user6454281 already:

```
esc_html_e( "I couldn't find the page you were looking for.", 'themename' );
```