# How to escape the single quote character in i18n translation strings?

Tags: translation, localization

How should I properly escape the single quote character in a translation string? I'm using it as an apostrophe. For example:

```
__( '404. This isn't the page you're looking for.', 'textdomain' );
```

I believe there are a few approaches but which is the proper way?

**Approach 1:** Using the backslash:

```
__( '404. This isn\'t the page you\'re looking for.', 'textdomain' );
```

**Approach 2:** Using the character entity:

```
__( '404. This isn&apos;t the page you&apos;re looking for.', 'textdomain' );
```

Comment: What does *proper* mean? How about [double quotes](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230107/how-to-handle-single-qoute-in-a-translatable-string-in-wordpress)?

Comment: Sorry, think it may be my British. _Proper_ "of the required or correct type or form; suitable or appropriate."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the first option. translated strings are supposed to be "raw", and escaped only by the calling function. In addition many will not understand what `&apos;` mean and how to translate it without looking at the actual page which can be annoying.